# Python split csv by date into list of list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, google-maps, dictionary, data-structures

I have a csv file. I want to split the data by the trips taken that day. I tried creating a List of list of dictionaries. I am hoping maybe there is a better approach? My end goal is to use the get a distance summary from google distance api for the distance traveled that day.

For example, for the below follow input:

Input csv file:

```
Address,City,State,ShowingDateTime
1234 Hodge Street,Brown,CA,1/4/17 12:00
9613 Llama Street,Downtown,CA,1/5/17 12:15
7836 Bob Street,Swamp,CA,1/5/17 12:15
2134 Cardinal Street,Ruler,CA,1/6/17 11:30
```

Expected data structure?:

```
List[ 
  List[Dict[1234 Hodge Street,Brown,CA,1/4/17 12:00],
  List[
    Dict[9613 Llama Street,Downtown,CA,1/5/17 12:15],
    Dict[7836 Bob Street,Swamp,CA,1/5/17 12:15]
  ],
  List[
    Dict[2134 Cardinal Street,Ruler,CA,1/6/17 11:30]
  ]
]
```

Attempt (not working):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from datetime import datetime
from googlemaps import Client
import requests
import csv
def read_csv(csv_file):  
  trip_list = []
  with open(csv_file) as File:
    reader = csv.DictReader(File, dialect='excel')   
    subtrip_list=[]
    previous_date=0
    for row in reader:
      current_date = datetime.strptime(row['ShowingDateTime'], '%m/%d/%y %H:%M').date()
      if previous_date==0:
        previous_date=current_date
      if current_date != previous_date:
        trip_list.append(subtrip_list)
        del subtrip_list[:]
      subtrip_list.append(row)
      previous_date=current_date
```

Comment: If you are going to specify a `departure_time` for requests to the Distance Matrix API, it needs to be in the future, not the past, as per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#departure-time). So your requests would have to omit the date/time info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the rows using the date string. `csv.DictReader` allows to you return the csv rows as dicts with keys as the csv header:

```
import csv
from itertools import groupby

func = lambda x: x['ShowingDateTime'].split()[0]

def read_csv(csv_file): 
    with open(csv_file) as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        lst = [list(grp) for _, grp in groupby(sorted(reader, key=func), func)]
    return lst
```

This returns a list of lists of dicts grouped by the dates. You may skip sorting step if the rows are already sorted by date.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used the google api, but my suggestion for a simpler approach would be to use pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates=['DateTime'])
print(df)
```

Outputs

```
                Address      City State            DateTime
0     1234 Hodge Street     Brown    CA 2017-01-04 12:00:00
1     9613 Llama Street  Downtown    CA 2017-01-05 12:15:00
2       7836 Bob Street     Swamp    CA 2017-01-05 12:15:00
3  2134 Cardinal Street     Ruler    CA 2017-01-06 11:30:00
```

From this point I think it is much easier to get whatever formats you prefer. But the data frame seems very useful for your use case. I would add another column for distance traveled from last point and plug the result from the google api in. But that is just me.